# Adding a member to a Discriminated Union that compares two values of the data type

Tags: types, f#, pattern-matching

I have just begun playing with F# and created the following toy problem. I have experimented with a number of syntax to do this but can't seem to get it right.

I have the following type

```
type Bar = 
    | DT of DateTime
    | O of float
    | H of float
    | L of float
    | C of float
```

And the following two examples

```
let barPass = 
    [ 
        O(13200.0);
        H(13220.0);
        L(13190.0);
        C(13210.0);
    ]  

let barFail = 
    [ 
        O(13200.0);
        H(13220.0);
        L(13290.0); // low is greater than high which is invalid
        C(13210.0);
    ]
```

I want to add a new member which checks to to see if the high is greater than or equal to the low. If have tried various pattern matchings but can't seem to get this right. The code below is incorrect but will suffice to demonstrate what I'm trying to do.

```
type Bar with
    member x.HiLoCheck() =
        match x with
        | x when (H >= L) -> true // <- compiler will not allow this
        | _ -> false
```

I think I need to break it down into a tuple but that too is still beyond my very limited f# experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you actually want to use a record as your data type rather than a list of Discriminated Unions.  Otherwise, your first step needs to be finding the `H` and 'L' elements in your list.

Something like

```
type Bar = 
    { DateTime : DateTime;
      O : float;
      H : float;
      L : float;
      C : float}
member x.HiLoCheck() = if x.H > x.L then true else false
```

**EDIT**

rough sketch of answer using the original DU + list version - will give errors if the required elements are not in the list but this can be fixed with `tryFind` instead of `find`

```
let checkhilo l =
    let high = l |> List.find (function |H(_) -> true |_ -> false)
    let low = l |> List.find (function |L(_) -> true |_ -> false)
    match high,low with
    |H(h),L(lo) -> if h>lo then true else false
    |_ -> failwith "shouldn't happen"
```

Comment: Thanks! This works as I wanted it to. I just started today so I am still not completely clear on the difference between Discriminate Union and Records.

Comment: @ChrisTarn The main difference is that a DU can be either `A` or `B` say you might have time able to be either a `DateTime` of a Unix time as an `int64`, whereas a record is more like a small class that stores a collection of data.

Comment: @JohnPlamer Thanks. Coming from Java/C# that makes things a lot clearer.